# jQuery increment the value of the nearest input undefined

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="tiny-up-down-wrapper">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="counter">
        <input class="count" type="text" value="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
jQuery('.tiny-up-down-wrapper .minus').click(function() {
    var theVal = jQuery(this).closest('input').val();
    alert(theVal);
});
```

This problem is that the alert is coming up us `undefined`. How can I fix this?

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). _"For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._" In general, this task is solved by combining [tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` is used to find the nearest parent element, whereas the `input` is a child of a sibling to the `.minus` element. Instead, you can use `closest()` to get the nearest `.tiny-up-down-wrapper` then `find()` to get the `input`. Try this:

```
$('.tiny-up-down-wrapper .minus').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tiny-up-down-wrapper').find('input').val();
    alert(theVal);
});
```

To actually decrement the value, you can do this:

```
$('.tiny-up-down-wrapper .minus').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tiny-up-down-wrapper').find('input').val(function(i, v) {
        return --v;
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46hrvenc/)

Comment: Just tested the bottom code to decrement and nothing happens ... any idea why?

Comment: My mistake. I updated the answer and added an example for you.